# Styling Datatables with Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

As jQuery Data Tables [Data Tables](http://www.datatables.net/) comes with CSS i would like to keep it styled the same way the whole website is styled.
Is there any way of styling Data Tables with Bootstrap?

Comment: Bootstrap 2 or 3? There are extra plugins on the data tables website for this specific purpose, e.g. https://editor.datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html

Comment: the latest bootstrap 3

Comment: you should be able to find everything you need from that link in the comment. Actually, the link should be https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html as in the answer below, I was on the wrong page after searching on Google. (The Editor for Data Tables rather than the main site).

Comment: Please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" since it means something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery Data Tables can integrate with bootstrap:

https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html

If you initiate it with the bootstrap plugin you will be able to style it using bootstrap CSS classes.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse you can style with bootstrap.

Just Use the Table and classes as of that in Bootstrap.

Eg :-

after including necessary Js and css files for bootsrap you could use thier classes it in your own table

```
 <table id="bus_list" class="table table-bordered responsive my_table dataTable" aria-describedby="bus_list_info">
```

for styling you could use your own style by taking thier classes and all eg shown below

example 1 [normal css]

```
.table th {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #0077BF;
}
```

example 2 [if example one didnt work- you could try out !important in css]

```
.table th {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #0077BF !important;
}
```

please let me know if you have any doubts !!!!